# Échouer et échec

Tags: étymologie

Ce matin je me suis étonné de découvrir que non seulement un, non seulement deux, mais *tous* les sens et mots dérivés du mot anglais *check / cheque* [ont pour origine la constellation *échec, échecs, échiquier*](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=check) par une série d'altérations imaginatives.

De là, j'ai dû vérifier la connexion entre *échouer* et  *échec* qui en serait le résultatif. Sauf ... j'ai vu qu'apparemment, j'ai inventé ladite connexion et qu'en effet, [« échouer » n'est apparu qu'au 16e siècle et que l'origine en est obscure](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A9chouer#%C3%89tymologie) !

Origines proposées dans l'article sur Wiktionnaire :

1. du latin *cautes* « rocher, écueil »
2. du français *échoir* avec changement de classe verbale
3. du français *escoudre* (ancienne variante de *secouer*)
4. du latin *exaquare* « enlever l'eau, mettre à sec »
5. du français *eschiver, eschuer* « esquiver, glisser de côté »

Il est intéressant de noter que dans l'exposition de la 2e hypothèse on lie le terme à « mis-en-échec » ... on a aussi cette phrase « si le cas y échet »  ... :)

En tout cas, voici ma question : L'origine d'*échouer* n'est pas connue. Imaginons une 6e hypothèse, celle que j'ai imaginée il y a longtemps dans la profondeur de mon ignorance : une dérivation du mot *échec* ou vice versa. Quels arguments pourrait-on donner pour ou contre ?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109551/discussion-on-question-by-luke-sawczak-echouer-et-echec).
As a reminder, if there is some phrasing that can be improved by a question's author and that does not fundamentally change the meaning of the question, the good practice is to **suggest an edit** (https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 1):

D'après le [Wikitionaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A9chec) le mot échec vient du persan *shâh mât* (« le roi est mort ») qui a donné *échec et mat*, il est donc peu probable que ce soit relié. Cependant rien n’exclut un croisement de racine.

À noter que les hypothèses fournies dans votre question sont très pertinentes, surtout avec comme exemple « une baleine échouée » où il s'agit réellement d'une sortie de l'eau d'où le latin "exaquare"

Je pense que *'si le cas y échet'* vient de échéant et n'est donc pas, de prime abord, relié à échec.

Comment: NB: dans les phrase "tu as échoué dans ta quête" et "tu as subi un échec" les deux mots ayant des significations différentes, produisent deux phrase avec une signification similaire, la parenté n'est ainsi pas tant éloignée.